# igraph adjacent edges based on attributes

Tags: r, igraph

For each vertex, I am interested in the number of its adjacent edges based on a condition. In the following example, the condition is having a different gender.

Example:

```
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
library(tidyverse)


nodes <- tibble(id = 1:4, 
                gender = c("M", "F", "F", "M"), 
                names = c("Bob", "Allie", "Mary", "Johnathon"))

edges <- tibble(from = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4),
                to = c(2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3))

network <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, vertices = nodes, directed = TRUE)

ggraph(network) + 
geom_edge_link(arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, 
'mm')), 
         start_cap = circle(4, 'mm'), 
         end_cap = circle(4, 'mm')) + 
geom_node_text(aes(label = names)) +
theme_graph()
```

[image: Example Plot]

Desired result:

```
id  name          adjacent_edges

1    Bob          1
2    Allie        1
3    Mary         2
4    Johnathon    1
```

Comment: Since Jonathan is next to both Mary and Allie, why do you have Jonathan = 1 in your expected answer? Bob and Allie also seem tp be wrong.

Comment: Your code seems to be identical to that in your previous, deleted question. Now the plot and the desired result are different, but inconsistencies seem to be the same... Ultimately you do seem to care about directions, so perhaps defining the graph as directed would fix your example?

Comment: yes, defining the graph as directed will hopefully clear things up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach combining base R with `igraph`:

```
nodes %>% 
  mutate(adjacent_edges = colSums(as.matrix(outer(gender, gender, `!=`) * as_adj(network)) != 0))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#      id gender names     adjacent_edges
#   <int> <chr>  <chr>              <dbl>
# 1     1 M      Bob                    1
# 2     2 F      Allie                  1
# 3     3 F      Mary                   2
# 4     4 M      Johnathon              1
```

Here

```
outer(gender, gender, `!=`)
```

builds a matrix with `TRUE` entries when genders are different, while `as_adj(network))` is the usual graph adjacency matrix. Then their product will have nonzero entries exactly when we want - in the case of connected nodes with different genders. Summing over such cases gives the desired result.

Here's another one, lengthier but also more transparent:

```
edges %>% full_join(nodes, by = c("from" = "id")) %>% 
  full_join(nodes, by = c("to" = "id"), suff = c(".from", ".to")) %>%
  group_by(to, names.to) %>% summarise(adjacent_edges = sum(gender.to != gender.from)) %>%
  rename(id = to, name = names.to)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   id [4]
#      id name      adjacent_edges
#   <dbl> <chr>              <int>
# 1     1 Bob                    1
# 2     2 Allie                  1
# 3     3 Mary                   2
# 4     4 Johnathon              1
```

In this case we start with the list of edges and twice add the list of nodes: one time as to have node information about the `from` edge, and one time as to have node information about the `to` edge, in the same row. Then it remains to summarise the data by summing all neighbours with different genders.